Difficulty in dockerizing a microservice which is already using redis container
I am using bullmq in that microservice and due to which I am using redis, now the issue is that now when I am trying to dockerize this microservice I am unable to do it as I am inexperienced so I can't really figure out what is going wrong. While trying to build it I am getting the following error:
project-service-1  | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
project-service-1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1607:16) {
project-service-1  |   errno: -111,
project-service-1  |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
project-service-1  |   syscall: 'connect',
project-service-1  |   address: '127.0.0.1',
project-service-1  |   port: 6379
project-service-1  | }

Where is the redis running? In another container, or in the host on which you're running docker?
If redis is running in another container, instead of using 127.0.0.1, try using the name you gave to the redis container.
If it's running on your host, try using host.docker.internal.
Let us know if either works, or what error you get.
